# Create folder sharepoint foundation Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a list with calculated value on it. I need that value to be a folder that get created in another lib.
how can I do that Programmatically. 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that `value` is you computed value, then you can create a folder in another library with name equals `value` using following code:

```
SPWeb web=SPContext.Current.Web; //just for example

var libUrl="host_relative_url_to_lib";
var docsLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.GetList(libUrl);
var libraryFolders = docsLibrary.RootFolder.SubFolders; //get all folders in lib
libraryFolders.Add(libUrl + "/" + value); //create a folder with name value
docsLibrary.Update(); //commit changes
```

Comment: How do I get the column value for folder name from the custom list called mylist? and would this be good to set as workflow after new item add. thanks

Comment: @Fm3 i can't understand what exactly you need, sorry. if you need to get a value from list item you can access it by internal name `item["InternalName"]`

Comment: yes a value from a list. So item["mylist"]. How do I specify columnName. how about